# How can shell pipeline buffers handle high bandwidth between processes?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, scheduler

Running `strace sh -c 'dd if=/dev/zero count=1 | md5sum'` it appears that the shell just creates a plain pipe between `dd` and `md5sum` and does not do any buffering of its own.

Since the pipe buffer size is 65536 on linux, how can there be no stalling due to `dd` filling the pipe buffer before `md5sum` can empty it ? Does the scheduler switch immediately from the `dd` task to `md5sum` as soon as the buffer is full, and immediately back once `md5sum` empties the buffer ? Would avoiding two task switches every 65536 bytes bring a significant bandwidth improvement ?